# Pinch to zoom out using UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

Strangely, my app's `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` is making it so that moving my fingers together zooms *in*, and moving my fingers apart zooms *out* -- which is the *opposite* of how iOS normally works.

I don't think it's relevant, but: I'm using this in a `SpriteKit` application.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` enable the normal iOS *pinch-out-to-zoom-in* and *pinch-in-to-zoom-out* behavior?

```swift
let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.pinchZoom))

self.thisView?.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
```

```swift
var normalCameraScale: CGFloat?
var accumulatedCameraScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
@objc func pinchZoom(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if self.normalCameraScale == nil {
        self.normalCameraScale = self.camera?.xScale ?? 1.0
        self.accumulatedCameraScale = self.normalCameraScale!
    }
    
    let maxScale: CGFloat = 10.0
        
    
    let newScale = gesture.scale * self.accumulatedCameraScale
        
    if newScale <= maxScale && newScale >= self.normalCameraScale! {
        self.camera?.setScale(newScale)
    }
        
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        self.accumulatedCameraScale = self.camera?.xScale ?? 1.0
    }
        
        
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623843/20287183

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336055/spritekit-pinch-to-zoom-camera/50623843#50623843), this formula solves this problem:

```
self.accumulatedCameraScale * 1 / gesture.scale
```

The full function:

```
var normalCameraScale: CGFloat?
var accumulatedCameraScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
@objc func pinchZoom(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  if self.normalCameraScale == nil {
       self.normalCameraScale = self.camera?.xScale ?? 1.0
       self.accumulatedCameraScale = self.normalCameraScale!
  }
    
  let maxScale: CGFloat = 10.0
        
  //This formula makes it work correctly:
  let newScale = self.accumulatedCameraScale * 1 / gesture.scale
        
  if newScale <= maxScale && newScale >= self.normalCameraScale! {
     self.camera?.setScale(newScale)
  }
        
  if gesture.state == .ended {
     self.accumulatedCameraScale = self.camera?.xScale ?? 1.0
  }
        
}
```

Comment: FYI - You don't need the `* 1` part of the formula.